# covariance matrix using np.matmul(data.T, data)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I've found online

```
d0 = pd.read_csv('./mnist_train.csv')
labels = d0.label.head(15000)
data = d0.drop('label').head(15000)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

#find the co-variance matrix which is : (A^T * A)/n
sample_data = standardized_data

# matrix multiplication using numpy
covar_matrix = np.matmul(sample_data.T , sample_data) / len(sample_data)
```

How does multiplying the same data gives `np.matmul(sample_data.T, sample_data)` covariance matrix? What is the co-variance matrix according to this tutorial I found online? The last step is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a better question for the math or stats stack exchange, but I'll answer here for now.

This comes from the [definition of covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Definition). The Wikipedia page (linked) gives a whole lot of detail, but covariance is defined as (in pseudo-code)

```
cov = E[dot((x - E[x]), (x - E[x]).T)]
```

for column vectors, but in your case you probably have row vectors, which is why the first element in your dot-product is transposed, not the second. The `E[...]` means expected value, [which is the mean for Gaussian-distributed data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution). When you perform [`StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), you are basically subtracting out the mean of the data, so that's why you don't explicitly do so in your dot product.

Note that `StandardScaler()` is also dividing by the variance, so it's normalizing everything to unit variance. *This is going to affect your covariance!* So if you need the actual covariance of the data without normalization, just calculate it with something like [`np.cov()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) from the numpy module.

Comment: what do you mean by row vectors? I have MNIST dataset. Also, I didn't get the point "you are basically subtracting out the mean of the data"? Can you expand a little more on that part.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `StandardScaler`. It removes the mean from the data (calculates the element-wise mean of the vectors and subtracts it), and also scales the variance to 1. Row vectors are arranged horizontally: `[1, 2, 3]`, column vectors vertically: `[[1], [2], [3]]`. It matters for the linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Let's build towards Covariance matrix step by step, first let's define variance.

The variance of some random variable X is a measure of how much values in the distribution vary on average with respect to the mean.

Now we have to define covariance.
Covariance is the measure of the joint probability for two random variables. It describes how the two variables change together. [Read here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html)

So now armed with that you can understand that Co-variance matrix is a matrix which shows how each feature varies with changes in other features. Which can be calculated as
[image: Co Variance Matrix calculation] and there you can see the equation that you are confused about formed at the bottom. If you have any further queries, comment down.

Image Source: Wikipedia.