# sklean Standard Scaler Ridge Pipeline

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to standardize features and then run a ridge regression.

As provided, the two answers are different.

When I set ridge=0, the answers are the same. When I remove StandardScaler and Dn, the answers are also the same.

I can't figure out how to reconcile the two versions (raw and using sklearn).

Thanks for your help

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

x = np.random.randn(100, 3)
y = np.random.randn(100, 2)

xx = x.T @ x
xy = x.T @ y
Dn = np.diag(1 / np.sqrt(np.diag(xx)))

ridge = 1

xx = Dn @ xx @ Dn
xy = Dn @ xy
beta_raw = Dn @ np.linalg.solve(xx + np.eye(len(xx)) * ridge, xy)
f_raw = x @ beta_raw

model = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler(with_mean=False)), ("regression", Ridge(ridge, fit_intercept=False))])
trained_model = model.fit(x, y)
f_ml = trained_model.predict(x)

print(f_ml[:3] / f_raw[:3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scaling by different values, check:

```
np.diag(Dn)
array([0.09699826, 0.10123938, 0.1016412 ])

model.steps[0][1].scale_
array([1.02603414, 0.98202661, 0.97598415])
```

Your standard deviation is the sqrt of the diagonal of the covariance matrix. Even though you are not centering your matrix, you still need to subtract the mean to get the covariance. See [this post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464444/covariance-matrix-using-np-matmuldata-t-data)

So if we do it correctly:

```
x_m = x.mean(axis=0)
x_cov = np.dot((x - x_m).T, x - x_m) / (x.shape[0])
Dn = np.diag(1 / np.sqrt(np.diag(x_cov)))

xx = x.T @ x
xy = x.T @ y

ridge = 1

xx = Dn @ xx @ Dn
xy = Dn @ xy
beta_raw = Dn @ np.linalg.solve(xx + np.eye(len(xx)) * ridge, xy)
f_raw = x @ beta_raw

model = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler(with_mean=False)), ("regression", Ridge(ridge, fit_intercept=False))])
trained_model = model.fit(x, y)
f_ml = trained_model.predict(x)

print(f_ml[:3] / f_raw[:3])

[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Suppose I wanted to make the sklearn pipeline resemble the raw way, instead of the other way around. Is there an easy way to do that?